# How Can I verity the results ordered as required in Selenium IDE, such as alphabetically sort or ID decreasing

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm new to the Selenium IDE, I need to verify whether the list order as required. We list out some records obtained from database. I know I can create two records with specific value, and achieve it using verifyOrdered or assertOrdered. But we have different sort orders such as sort by ID DESC or name alphabetically ASC, and we have pagination tools, so the created two records may not displayed in same page.

So is there any useful method that I can verify the order for specific locator list without knowing the values, such as ID desc? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you check a list, are at least two items of the list on the first page of results?

I test a site that has multiple search results of varying types, and have tests that verify sort order for all of them.

1. You'll need to check to see if there is some way to verify which direction the list is sort, either ASC or DSC.  Check for an element that might be something like: "css=th.sortasc" or "css-th.sortdsc", some way to verify the direction.
2. Once you can do that, grab any two values from the list (maybe the first one in the list, and the next one or one further down before pagination) and then compare them to verify one is greater than or less than the other.
3. You may need to do some cleaning up of the data, depending on if it's supposed to be numeric or a string.

I'm using RobotFramework with Selenium to do our tests, here's some sample code that does what you're doing. 
 {

```
Click Element    ${Name_Column_Header} #clicks the header to sort the column. 
Sleep    2s
Element Should Be Visible    css=th.sortdsc > a   #verifies the sort caret is shown and it's descending. 
#next 3 lines grab the text from the field (in this case, person names)
${Name1}    Get Text    css=td.ng-binding
${Name2}    Get Text    //tbody[2]/tr/td
${Name3}    Get Text    //tbody[3]/tr/td
#next lines grab just the last name from each name, since list is sorted by last name. 
${N1}    Fetch From Right    ${Name1}    ${SPACE}
${N2}    Fetch From Right    ${Name2}    ${SPACE}
${N3}    Fetch From Right    ${Name3}    ${SPACE}
#next two lines do the compare, verifying that the name in line 1 is greater than the name in line 2, and line 2 name is greater than line 3
Should Be True    '${N1}' >= '${N2}'
Should Be True    '${N2}' >= '${N3}'
```

}

In selenium IDE, the commands would be very similar.

{

```
<!--Sort by name-->
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Name</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<!--Grab values for name from 1st and 2nd row-->
<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td><locator value>
    <td>1stRowName</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>storeText</td>
    <td><locator value>
    <td>2ndRowName</td>
</tr>
<!--evaluate that 1st row name is less than or equal to 2nd row name-->
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>var isLess = false; isLess = eval(storedVars['1stRowName'] &lt;  storedVars['2ndRowName']);</td>
    <td>isLess</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyExpression</td>
    <td>${isLess}</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
```

}

Hope this helps. 
-- Klendathu

Comment: yes, it seems that that's the only way I found for now. but maybe the two locator value is equal so I finally decided to create two records with different value that I can compare with and I need to narrow the search condition so that those two records are displayed in same page.